# res.json() in callback of res.render() on GET

Tags: node.js, express

I'm initializing a kind of chatbot application on GET on a certain page. I would like to:

1. Render the page (Express): `res.render()`
2. When it's done (callback), execute a function (`initializeDialogue()`) that will, among other things, launch a server side java application, and then return a JSON object with a message that has to be printed on the same rendered page:  `res.json()`

The problem is that I can't find a way to `res.render()` and then `res.json()` on the same page. I could

Here is a part of the code:

```
router.get('/dialogue', function (req, res) {

  // Render the HTML (from dialogue.jade)
  res.render('dialogue', { title: 'Dialogue' }, function (err, html) {

    // Initialize the dialogue (launch a java child_process, etc.)
    // Slow! >2000ms
    initializeDialogue(function (err, result) {

      // From returned result, send a JSON message to the same page
      res.status(200).json({
        type: result.type,
        speaker: result.speaker,
        utterance: result.utterance
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I could of course `initializeDialogue()` before rendering the page, and passing the JSON message as argument of `res.render()`, but since the `initializeDialogue()` process is so heavy, it lasts more than 2 seconds and I don't want to have the user wait that long before the page is rendered (he can however wait that long before receiving the first message).

Is there any solution ?

Comment: You should better send a request from the client, when page is rendered, to get `initializeDialogue()` response.

Comment: Thank you! I suppose that request typically would be sent via jQuery. How can I make sure that such request would only happen once, the first time the user launches the page?

Comment: You can use cookies or local storage. You can also perform such a request on every page opening, but responde to it, basing on some server side conditions.